# Infinitely many finite groups with given automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Is there a finite group $G$ for which there exist infinitely many finite groups $A$ (up to isomorphism) with automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(A)\cong G$?

Comment: Why the downvote? I had a dream yesterday's night where a math problem emerged. To make it well-defined, I need this question answered.

Comment: Then maybe put effort into formulating proper sentences with correct grammar. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Probably because, without access to your dream, there's little to motivate why it's an interesting question.  Also there is a grammatical mistake.  Though I am not the one who downvoted, and they should have explained.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Please give some additional information.

Comment: I consider it interesting. Seems like a pretty natural question for someone to pose. I mean, set theorists have considered transfinite towers of automorphism groups, seemingly just because. It's rather classical to ask which groups may arise from a certain group-creating process, indeed even automorphism groups in categories of fields (the Inverse Galois Problem). The downvotes I believe are silly and unjustified.

Comment: That said, poor English (for the sake of using quantifiers clearly) and allusions to dreams isn't helping. I have edited the question for clarity in case there really are any who had trouble reading it.

Comment: Interesting problem, very poorly posed question.

Comment: @runway44 I added a formal LaTeX. It seems it conflicted with your edit. Would to do it again?